# load js scripts only when needed

Tags: javascript, webpack, lazy-loading

I've been trying to optimize my webpage by removing uncessary javascript loading. In my index page I have only a slider but I have some other html pages with forms too.

The way my webpack is now, it creates a single "app.js" with all scripts together: slider stuff and forms validation.

But I don't have any forms on index.html so I think its wrong to load any form validation script as I will not use any of them.

How can I use lazy-loading to import only the javascript files I need for my pages? Example: index.html will only load the `slider.js` and my other html page which contains forms will load only load my `form_validation.js` script.

Comment: Are you using ReactJS?

Comment: Google code splitting

Comment: You may need http://requirejs.org
If you use builder, tree-shacking (RollupJS) or code splitting (ParcelJS, Webpack) can help you too.

Comment: You may be interested in [multiple entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/output/#multiple-entry-points) and [this official Webpack plugin for splitting chunks](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/), which do this very thing mostly transparently.

Comment: No, I am purely using webpack and npm to add modules to my website. I already googled but I could not find an answer. If I did, I would not be here...

Comment: @IsiahMeadows I read this webpack but I dont understand how am I supposed to hell it which php pages must contain this or that js file? I already have several chunks but I am using a php if and else to determin, based on a $_GET value, which script to include. I would like a more automated way, do you know some?

Answer (score 1):

According to the **Webpack** [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/lazy-loading/), you can do something like this.

**On the index.html page**

```
document.onload = async function(){
    const slider = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "slider" */ 'slider');
}
```

**On the HTML page where you have the form**

```
document.onload = async function(){
    const form_validation = await import(/* webpackChunkName: "form_validation" */ './form_validation');
}
```

Comment: hmm.. But then I would have to add manually in each of my pages this code, right? They way I designed my website is via GET parameters, which I use `include_once` inside some `div` tag that holds what to display given the page name. This way, the js script that you said would be before the `app.js` which is included in the bottom of the page. Can't I have a more automatic way?

Comment: Well, the documentation says that it loads the particular JS chunk only once and once it's loaded, you don't have to reload it again in every page.

Comment: I found that `htmlwebpack` is ALMOST what I want. I can specify with it what chunks determined page must have. But, I need to use a template file for it to work, and I don't want to rewrite all my website to template pattern. Do you know any solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Sorry :(